# Time calculation class issue

Tags: php, time

I have create the class that following, that calculating the time before a time frame, the time inside the time frame, and the time next to time frame.

More specific, I creating a taxi booking system. The taxi has normal charges for day trips, and double charges for night trips.

The web site owner, has the ability to set the time's that night rate starts and ends. As an example let's say that normal **taxi night rates** start at **00:00** and ends at **05:00**, and the night charges for **mini bus** taxi, start at **23:00** and ends at **06:00**.

At the time that the client makes the order, the Google maps calculating the trip duration, so let's say also that the trip is two hours long.

Based on this scenario, in case of **taxi** the end user must be charged with **1 hour** of normal rate and **1 hour** with double rates. In case of **mini bus** the end user must be charged **2 hours** in **double rate**, while the night rates for mini bus starts at **23:00**.

With my class, in its current state the first example works fine, but the second is wrong and I cannot find the reason.

```
<?php
class tm
{
    private $start_hour     =   0;    //  The hour that the trip starts
    private $start_minute   =   0;    //  The minute that the trip starts
    private $from_hour      =   0;    //  The hour that night rates start
    private $from_minute    =   0;    //  The minute that night rates start
    private $to_hour        =   0;    //  The hour that night rates ends
    private $to_minute      =   0;    //  The minute that night rates ands
    private $duration       =   0;    //  Total trip duration
    private $night_duration =   0;    //  The overall night trip time in minutes
    private $day_duration   =   0;    //  The overall day trip time in minutes
    private $totalHours     =   0;    //  The total duration hours
    private $totalMinutes   =   0;    //  The total duration minutes
    private $extraMinutes   =   0;    //  Extra minutes to calculate

    /**
     * Construct duration calculator class
     * 
     * @param   $start_date     Timestamp   |   The trip start date/time as a timestamp
     * @param   $duration       Seconds     |   The duration time in seconds
     * @param   $night_start    Timestamp   |   The date/time that night rates start as a timestamp
     * @param   $night_end      Time        |   The date/time that night rates end as a timestamp
     */
    public function __construct($start_date = '', $duration = 1, $night_start = '', $night_end = '')
    {
        $this->start_hour   =   date('H', $start_date);
        $this->start_minute =   date('i', $start_date);
        $this->duration     =   ($duration / 60);               //  Convert seconds to minutes
        $this->from_hour    =   date('H', $night_start);
        $this->from_minute  =   date('i', $night_start);
        $this->to_hour      =   date('H', $night_end);
        $this->to_minute    =   date('i', $night_end);

        $this->calculate();
    }

    private function calculate()
    {
        $this->getHoursMinutes();
        $current_hour   =   $this->start_hour % 24;
        $is_first_loop  =   true;

        for($minute = 0; $minute < $this->duration; $minute++)
        {
            $current_minute     =   ($this->start_minute + $minute) % 60;

            if($current_minute  ==  0 && $is_first_loop == false)
            {
                $current_hour   =   ($current_hour + 1) % 24;
            }
            else if($current_minute == 59)
            {
                $is_first_loop = false;
            }

            if(($current_hour >= $this->from_hour && $current_hour < $this->to_hour))
            {
                $this->night_duration++;
            }
            else
            {
                $this->day_duration++;
            }
        }
    }

    private function getHoursMinutes()
    {
        $this->totalHours   =   round($this->duration / 60 / 60, 0);
        $this->totalMinutes =   round($this->duration / 60, 0);
        $this->extraMinutes =   round(($this->duration / 60) % 60, 0);
    }

    public function getDayDuration($inSeconds = true)
    {
        if($inSeconds == true)
        {
            return $this->day_duration * 60;
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->day_duration;
        }
    }

    public function getNightDuration($inSeconds = true)
    {
        if($inSeconds == true)
        {
            return $this->night_duration * 60;
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->night_duration;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Based on the examples above let's say I have the following code:

```
<?php
    $trip_start_timestamp    =   strtotime('01/09/2013 23:00');
    $duration                =   strtotime('01/10/2013 01:00') - $trip_start_timestamp;
    $night_start             =   strtotime('00:00:00');            // This is the time for taxi start night rate
    $night_end               =   strtotime('05:00:00');            // This is the time for taxi end night rate

    $taxi       =    new tm($trip_start_timestamp, $duration, $night_start, $night_end);

    echo "TAXI NIGHT DURATION<br />";
    echo "Day : " . $taxi->getDayDuration() . '<br />';
    echo "Night : " . $taxi->getNightDuration() . '<br />';

    $trip_start_timestamp    =   strtotime('01/09/2013 23:00');
    $duration                =   strtotime('01/10/2013 01:00') - $trip_start_timestamp;
    $night_start             =   strtotime('23:00:00');            // This is the time for taxi start night rate
    $night_end               =   strtotime('06:00:00');            // This is the time for taxi end night rate

    $miniBus    =    new tm($trip_start_timestamp, $duration, $night_start, $night_end);

    echo "<br />MINI BUS NIGHT DURATION<br />";        
    echo "Day : " . $miniBus->getDayDuration() . '<br />';
    echo "Night : " . $miniBus->getNightDuration() . '<br />';
?>
```

End the result of the above code is the following:

```
TAXI NIGHT DURATION  
Day : 3600  
Night : 3600  



MINI BUS NIGHT DURATION  
Day : 3600  
Night : 3600
```

As you can see the above results are wrong, because the minibus night rate starts at **23:00**, so the result should be Day: **0 Night: 7200**

Finally, note that I have apply several modifications in the line:

```
if(($current_hour >= $this->from_hour && $current_hour < $this->to_hour))
```

Because I believe that the issue is this line. Unfortunately I have not find any solution.

Comment: 1. It feels like you're going about this the wrong way 2. You can extend classes (making specialized versions for miniBus) 3. Your class just calculates the hours of day/night rates ?

Comment: 1. Do you have any better solution ? 2. The cars are generated dynamicly, so the classes cannot be predicted. 3. The class calculate the amount of day and night trip. In the above example the trip is two hours long. So, based on the above example the taxi must be charged only one hour with normal rate and one hour with double rate based on the time frame, the mini bust must be charged for two hours.

Comment: It is probably easier to temporarily convert the times to unix time stamps and take the difference between start and end

Comment: @dualed can you provice any example ? I supose you understand what I need. I need to divide the total time in normal rates and double rates based on trip duration and the night start time.

Comment: @dualed that's actually what I was thinking on the solution. That's what I feel is the proper approach... need to understand the actual requirements...

Comment: I have try the timestamp aproach but still no solution for that issue. @Khez Can you provide any example ?

Comment: @MerianosNikos Yes I can! But first, can a trip be longer than 1 day ?

Comment: In reality I supose that the trip cannot be longer than a day, but still I must give this solution too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pseudo-code:

```
$now = time(); // = Unit Time Stamp
$end = getEndOfTripTime(); // = Unix Time Stamp
$isnight = isNightRate($now);

if($isnight)
{
  if(getNextNightRateEnd($now) > $end)
  {
    $NightRateSeconds = $end - $now;
  }
  else
  {
    $NightRateSeconds = getNextNightRateEnd($now) - $now;
    $DayRateSeconds = $end - getNextNightRateEnd($now);
  }
}
else
{
   // etc.
}
```

I assume you can fill in the rest for `!$isnight`.

You could also think of `$now` as `$start` (`= getStartOftriptime()`) to plan trips ahead of time.

Comment: This is not so helpfull. Let's say, the software owner need the night rate for taxi to be started at 23:30, then the client rent the taxi for a trip that requires 50 minutes to be completed and choose the trip to start at 23:15. Based on your code how to get the 15 minutes that are charged with normal rate and the rest 35 minutes that are charged with the night rate ?

Comment: I don't see the problem, where do you see it? `minutes = seconds/60` by the way